# Could not find a match for URL Workbench

Tags: rest, workbench, restresource

I am trying to test my code from workbench by sending an xml file to my @restresource global class. I have a @httpPost method through which I wan to insert the record. When I try to send a request to my class I am getting error : URL not found 
My class code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead')
global with sharing class ParentRest {
@HttpPost
global static Lead doPost() {
    RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
    system.debug('The request ' + req);
    return null;
}
}
```

My workbench Url

```
/services/apexrest/lead
```

Workbench header

```
Content-Type: application/XML; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
```

Error on workbench:

```
 [ {
 "errorCode" : "NOT_FOUND",
 "message" : "Could not find a match for URL /lead"
 } ]
```

What will be the reason. Anyone have any idea what will be the reason?
Please guide me how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have solved the issue. Solution: If you have namespace defined in salesforce you need to define it with `/services/apexrest/namespace/lead`

Comment: This was my exact issue. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: Yeah Now I got the solution :)